# Reversing the even characters of a word

Tags: java, recursion

I was wondering how one would go about making all of the even characters in a word switch with it's partner on the other side of the word.

For example: abc would look like cba or monkey would be eonkMy.

I am looking for one method that would only move the even characters of a string through the use of recursion or calling the method in the return.

```
public static String revEven(String str)
{
    if(str.length() == 0)
        return "";
    return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + revEven(str.substring(0, str.length() -1));

}
```

The output of the current soulution is:

```
yeknom
edcba
```

I need the output to be:

```
yonkmy
ebcda
```

Comment: Is your monkey example correct? If so, then I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but regardless, you don't need to use recursion, just get all the characters in a char array, then loop over them and swap them with array.length - i (i your loop index), or whatever you want to swap them with. Watch out for 0 length arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

convert string into `Char[]`

```
String input="monkey";
char[] inparr=input.toCharArray();
int len=input.length;
 for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++) //iterate till half length that will work
 {
    if(i%2==0)
    {
      //character is even
        //swap i and len-i index
        int temp=inparr[i];
        inparr[i]=inparr[len-i];
        inparr[i]=temp;
    }
    else
    {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `StringBuilder`. Only loop for the first half of the input `String` and increment your loop counter by `2`. Something like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("monkey");
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() / 2; i += 2) {
    int p = sb.length() - i - 1;
    char ch = sb.charAt(p);
    sb.setCharAt(p, sb.charAt(i));
    sb.setCharAt(i, ch);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Which outputs

```
yoknem
```

if you change the declaration of `int p` to

```
int p = sb.length() - i - 2;
```

you get

```
eonkmy
```

Comment: Which isn't what the question says it's supposed to output.

Comment: @bim true, but is the swapped even characters. Edited to provide an example that does produce the requested output.

Comment: Yeah, the question isn't clear, I read it like you did until I looked closely at the monkey example. I suspect the monkey example is just wrong (as I suggested in my comment on the question itself), so I didn't vote your answer down or anything, just pointing out it didn't *really* match the question.

Comment: @blm Well, it does now. :)

Comment: Yep, so changed my "doesn't" to "didn't". :-)